# las llaves de cifrado de google chrome no se guardan en mi archivo tlskeys.log

Tags: linux, variables-globales, wireshark

estoy intentando decifrar las conexiones mediante wireshark, estoy intentando crear una variable de entorno para que las llaves se guarden dentro y asi poder utilizarlas en wireshark, solia hacer esto en windows, pero me quiero amoldar mas a kali ya que tiene un entorno mas adaptable para realizar esto, a continuacion dejo los comando que estoy utilizando, vale aclarar que todos los comandos e incluso abro google chrome siempre desde la misma terminal,

```
export SSLKEYLOGFILE=/home/enzo/Escritorio/tlskeys.log
```

luego verifico si el achivo se creo satisfatoriamente con

```
echo $SSLKEYLOGFILE
```

y recivo

```
/home/enzo/Escritorio/tlskeys.log
```

eso quiere decir que esta la variable esta creada.

pero lamentablemente a la hora de abrir google chrome y visitar varios sitios, las llaves no aparecen en el archivo tlskeys.log que habia creado previamente, necesitaria saber si estoy haciendo las cosas bien y de no ser asi que es lo que hago mal? saludos